# Storing socket.io comments on a blog detail page as an array in the MongoDB entry of said blog post

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, socket.io

I asked a similar question yesterday but I'm afraid I asked before I was really ready to tackle the issue I described then.

A quick rundown of my app and what I need help for:

- Live Q&A app with discussions and comments (structure roughly similar to a general blog CMS)
- I use Socket.io to live-add my comments to a MongoDB collection "comments", all comments are being stored in here.
- I want the comments that belong to one specific discussion post to keep showing persistently on said discussion page and then the same for all the others.

So, on my localhost:3000/discussions/2 (where 2 is a sequence-generated incremental ID) I want all of my comments on that discussion to persistently display there. Then the comments for discussions/3 on said page.

My lecturer told me I should work by nesting an array of comments inside my discussion Schema. However, I don't know how to properly do this. (should I port over part of my comments Schema and add it into the array or should I somehow link my entire comments Schema/model to that array)

My two models/schemas for comments and discussions are in separate files.

This is my code:

../www (root)

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

 var app = require('../app');
 var debug = require('debug')('Webtech2:server');
 var http = require('http');

 //models
 var Comment = require("../models/comments");
 var Discussion = require("../models/discussions");


/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

 var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
 app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

 var server = http.createServer(app);

//Sockets komen hier
var io = require("socket.io")(server);

io.on("connection", function(socket) {
  socket.on("postComment", function(data) {

    console.log("Socket.io: server received POST");
    //log data naar console
    console.log("Client data log:"+data);

    //stuur 'data' naar iedereen
    io.sockets.emit("update_comment", data);

    Comment.create(data, function(err,res) {
      console.log(res+" added to DB");
      io.emit('update:', res);
    });
  });
});

//op connection doe dit:
io.on("connected", function(socket) {
  Comment.find().exec(function(err, output) {
    socket.emit('show_data', output);
    console.log("Output: "+output);
  });
});


/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

 server.listen(port);
 server.on('error', onError);
 server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

 function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

 function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
  ? 'Pipe ' + port
  : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
    console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
    process.exit(1);
    break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
    console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
    process.exit(1);
    break;
    default:
    throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

 function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
  ? 'pipe ' + addr
  : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

/models/discussions.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Comment = require('../models/comments');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//schema discussions
var DiscussionSchema = new Schema({
    uid: Number,  
    author: String,
    title: String,
    body: String,
    category: String,
    location: String,
    date: Date,
    comments: [ { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment'} ]
},
{ collection : 'discussions' });



// model
var Discussion = mongoose.model('Discussion', DiscussionSchema, 'discussions');

// console.log(Discussion.comments);

module.exports = Discussion;
```

/models/comments.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    //schema comments
    var CommentSchema = new Schema({
        // cmt_uid: Number,
        cmt_discussion_id: Number,
        cmt_author: String,
        cmt_body: String,
        cmt_date: Date,
        cmt_hourDate: Date,
        cmt_minuteDate: Date,
        cmt_secondDate: Date
    },
    { collection : 'comments'});

    //model 
    var Comment = mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema, 'comments');

    module.exports = Comment;
```

/public/javascripts/sockets_comments.js (jQuery responsible for comment form logic on relevant Jade page)

```
//jquery voor sockets -- socket.io documentation/
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("socket init ok");
    var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000");
    var result = "";

    //data ophalen en naar mongod
    $("#commentForm").on("submit", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //om insta refesh te voorkomen, gezien in les

        var Author = $("#commentName").val();
        var BodyText = $("#commentBody").val();
        var comment_uid = $("#comment_discus_id").val();
        var commentDate = new Date().toDateString();
        var hourDate = new Date().getHours();
        var minuteDate = new Date().getMinutes();
        var secondDate = new Date().getSeconds();

        //mongo schema includen
        result = {
            "cmt_author": Author,
            "cmt_body": BodyText,
            "cmt_date": commentDate,
            "cmt_discussion_id": comment_uid,
            "cmt_hourDate": hourDate,
            "cmt_minuteDate": minuteDate,
            "cmt_secondDate": secondDate
        };

        console.log(Author+""+BodyText+""+commentDate);

        socket.emit("postComment", result);
        console.log(result); 
    });

    socket.on("update_comment", function(data) {
        console.log(data);

        $("#commentsShow").prepend("<li class='slideClass'>"+"<b style='font-size: 1.6em; margin-bottom: 15px;'>"+data.cmt_author+" commented: "+"</b><br><br><p class='markers' style='padding-top: -6px; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; max-width:500px; margin-left: 15px;'>"+data.cmt_body+"</p><br><br><span style='font-size=0.2em; float: right; margin-top: -10px;'>At "+data.cmt_hourDate+":"+data.cmt_minuteDate+":"+data.cmt_secondDate+" on "+data.cmt_date+"</span></li>");
        $(".slideClass").slideDown("slow");
        $("#commentName").val("");
        $("#commentBody").val("");       

    });
});    


    //loop visual data from db
    // socket.on("showData", function(output) {
    //     //loop
    //     for(var comments = 0; comments < output.length; comments++)
    //     {
    //         ////
    //     }
    // });
```

routes/discussions.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Discussion = require('../models/discussions');
var Comment = require('../models/comments');
var User = require('../models/users');
var Sequence = require('../models/sequences');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

//HOOFDPAGINA DISCUSSIONS, ALLE DISCUSSIONS UITLUSSEN
router.get('/', function(req, res, next){

    // alle db records uitlussen, op render alldiscussions
    var db = req.db;
    Discussion.find().exec(function(err, discussions){
        res.render('all_discussions', {
            "all_discussions" : discussions,
            "title": "Discussions"
        });
    });
});

// ROUTE VOOR CREATE A DISCUSSION
router.get('/create', function(req, res, next){
    res.render('add_discussion', {title: 'Diskussr'});

});

//ROUTE VOOR SHAREN DISCUSSIONS (MET UNIQUE QUESTION ID)
router.get('/:id', function(req, res) {

    // ID VAN URL
    var discussion_id = req.params.id;

    // ZOEK VRAAG OP ID
    Discussion.findOne().where("uid", discussion_id).exec(function(err, discussion){
        if (err) {
            console.log("No discussion with given ID found.");
            } else {
                console.log("ID found!");
                res.render('discussion_detail', {discussion : discussion});
            }
        });
});

// ADD TO DATABASE MET FORM/UID
router.post('/submit', function(req, res) {
    console.log('POST Submit received');

    //set DB
    var db = req.db;
    //console.log(db);

    //uid toevoegen aan elke insert() in diskussrb/discussions
    Sequence.findOne().where("name", "discussions").exec(function(err, sequence){
        console.log("uid:"+sequence.next);

        //var UniqueID
        var uid = sequence.next;

        //sequence uid+1
        sequence.next+=1;
        sequence.save();

        //form vals
        var author = req.body.name;
        var title = req.body.title;
        var body = req.body.body;
        var category = req.body.category;
        var date = new Date();
        var location = req.body.location;

        //insert and save naar diskussrdb/discussions
        new Discussion({
            "uid": uid,
            "author" : author,
            "title" : title,
            "body" : body,
            "category": category,
            "date" : date,
            "location" : location
        }).save(function (err, doc) {
            if (err) {
                res.send("Database submit error");
                console.log("Database insert FAILED");
            }
            else {
                console.log("Database insert SUCCESS");
                res.redirect("/discussions/"+uid);
            }
        });
    });
});

//ROUTE VOOR POST COMMENT (SAVED NAAR COLLECTIONS/COMMENTS -- GEEN LINK AAN DISCUSSION)
router.post('/submit_comment', function(req, res) {
    console.log("comment post received");

    var db = req.db;

    Discussion.findOne().where('', '').exec(function(err, comment){

        //form vals
        var cmt_author = req.body.commentName;
        var cmt_body = req.body.commentBody;
        var cmt_date = new Date();

        // new Comment({
        //  "cmt_author": cmt_author,
        //  "cmt_body": cmt_body,
        //  "cmt_date": cmt_date
        // }).save(function (err, doc){
        //  if (err) {
        //      res.send("Comment submit to DB failed");
        //      console.log("Comment insert FAILED");
        //  }
        //  else {
        //      console.log("Comment insert SUCCESS");
        //      res.redirect("/discussions/"+uid);
        //  }
        // });


    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I made a hidden form on my Jade view which automatically takes the discussion.uid (created by a sequencing collection with AI) as a value and stores it in each comment.

I thought that way I could do something like find.comments where comments.uid == discussions.uid, though I heard MongoDB really isn't made to do this by default.

Thank you for your time.

My apologies if I have been flooding StackOverflow with my questions lately.

Comment: You can use mongodb populate with refs. See this link on how to use it with mongoose; http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Basically that will embed comments ids to discussion schema and you can populate the comments to print anywhere when it is needed.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out.

Could you provide me with a sample syntax, though? Do I need to add something to my routes files too?

Also, does it matter that my two models are in separate files?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still stuck. How do I properly add the code required for getting this data. I assume it's in my routes? I've included my routes file in the main post for more info.